# Which azure-pipelines.yml runs in build-validation?

Tags: azure-pipelines, git-branch, pull-request

I have two questions about build validation in *Branch policies* in Azure DevOps.

1. When defining a build validation policy, there is a *Build pipeline* drop-down list, listing all the pipelines in the project (including pipelines that are defined for different repos).
   What is the point in selecting a build pipeline that's defined in repo *Foo* as a build validation pipeline for a branch in repo *Bar*? Anyhow, as far as I tried, it's not even possible.
2. Say there are branches *master* and *feature*, both containing an *azure-pipelines.yml* file defining a pipeline, and I want to set a build validation policy for *master*. Which one of the two *azure-pipelines.yml* versions will run when I issue a pull request?

It'll be great if someone could answer these questions with a wider context of how the whole mechanism of build validation works.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're right, we can't queue a build of one repo to a PR of a second repo, if you choose in the build validation a pipeline of another repo you will get this error:

[image]

2. If the `azure-pipelines.yml` file is different in the branches, the behavior is like any file. if the YAML in the `feature` branch can be merged into `master` without issues so the YAML of the `feature` will be queued, because before the build is running, Azure DevOps perform a merge behind the scenes.  if there are conflicts between the branches (in the YAML file) the build will not be queued until you will solve the conflicts, then the build will take the version after you solved the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about no 1. But I can say that for no 2 is that it will run azure-pipelines.yml that exist on that branch.